# Global exception handler in Web API not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, exception, elmah

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767759/global-exception-handler-in-web-api-2-2-is-not-catching-an-exception) but that issue was specifically concerning a 404 error.

I have added Elmah as a global handler as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx). If I raise an error in code Elmah catches it just fine, but if I have a SQL error from EF via a controller for example, it is not caught - the exception message is returned in the json as a 500 error.

According to this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) there are a few cases where an exception can't be caught but my case doesn't seem to be one of them.

Can anyone please explain why a global error handler in WebAPI won't catch a SQL exception?

Here's my handler:

```
public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(context.Exception));
    }
}
```

and here's where it's registered in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ----
    config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your EF code is not in a try/catch block already?

Comment: Can you show us the code, in the controller and its dependencies, where the exception occurs?

Comment: There is no try catch in the EF code - this is the controller:    [Route("api/StaffMembers/{filterCriteria}/{partName}")]  <br/>
        public IQueryable<StaffMember> GetStaffMembers(string filterCriteria, string partName = "")
        {
            return db.StaffMembers.Where(a => a.FirstName.Contains(partName) || a.LastName.Contains(partName)).OrderBy(c => c.LastName);            
        }

Comment: Oops, couldn't figure out how to format a comment within the 5 mins allowed..